# Database TLS and certificates clarification

Tags: tls, certificates, mongodb

Is this behaviour of MongoDB secure?

1. Database TLS is turned on and the client's cert .pem is loaded on the machine. When the client-side app is launched and communicating with the database, the cert works with TLS and is able to save data from app to database.
2. However, using [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass), I turn on TLS but did not load the client-side cert, and tick the option "allow invalid cert", and Compass is able to log into the database.

Comment: Where was "allow invalid cert"? In the Compass tool or somewhere else?

Comment: and have you looked up Mongo's documentation on this? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl-clients/#avoid-use-of---tlsallowinvalidcertificates-option

Comment: This is the part I don't quite understand. If server is properly hardened, should mongo compass still allow user somehow connect to it?

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't understand what you are asking. And you have not answered my first question. Can you clarify or rephrase your question?

Comment: Are you sure that you activated TLS Client Authentication on the MongoDB side? Your database logs should tell you how the client is authenticated. The client may be ready for certificate authentication, but is the server doesn't ask for it it won't do it.

Comment: The mongo cfg file has the TLS option enabled. I will take a look what was captured in the server log.

Comment: TLS  will only authenticate the server. You need TLS Client Authentication are different things. See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/security-x.509/#security-auth-x509

Comment: At database, mongo cfg updated with tls enabled and pointing to the file path of pem cert which this cert contains of CA, client cert, and procate key (when I view it via notepad). The client cert is stored at the host machine where the client app is hosted (I run mongo compass at this host machine too). I believed the client cert is what you meant the x.509  cert for tls client authentication purposes.

Comment: Further reading, if mongo compass sucess login, does it mean tls connection established, what does it means insufficient authentication? Like i cannot add data to db or query anything? Please help me to understand it. Starting in MongoDB 4.2, if you specify --tlsAllowInvalidateCertificates or net.tls.allowInvalidCertificates: true when using x.509 authentication, an invalid certificate is only sufficient to establish a TLS connection but it is insufficient for authentication.